# как разбить бинарную "строку" в float'ы по 4 байта?

Tags: node.js, binary

в Node.js

в PHP вродебы все понятно:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $data_num/4; $i++) { //4 байта на 
    $tmpbuffer = '';
    $index = $i * 4;
    $tmpbuffer .= $buffer[$index+3];
    $tmpbuffer .= $buffer[$index+2];
    $tmpbuffer .= $buffer[$index+1];
    $tmpbuffer .= $buffer[$index];
    array_push($result_array, unpack("f", $tmpbuffer));
}
```

Сделал для node.js, но числа не сходятся с теми, которые получаются после php скрипта

```
let result_array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data_num/4; i++) { //4 байта на float
    let tmpBuffer = '';
    let index = i * 4;
    tmpBuffer = tmpBuffer + buffer[index+3].toString();
    tmpBuffer = tmpBuffer + buffer[index+2].toString();
    tmpBuffer = tmpBuffer + buffer[index+1].toString();
    tmpBuffer = tmpBuffer + buffer[index].toString();
    result_array.push(Buffer.from(tmpBuffer, 'binary').readFloatBE(0));
}
```

console.log(result_array);

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой, читайте доки https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readfloatbe_offset

Comment: Вероятно, аналог PHP оператора `.=` - это `+=` в JS?

Comment: Если у вас уже есть буфер, так прочитайте из него сразу чистло

Comment: В этом буфере подряд идет много чисел, а не одно.

Comment: Откуда взялся buffer и какого он типа?

Comment: buffer это тот самый буфер с бинврными данными

Comment: Ну раз он буфер см. ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
let result_array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data_num; i += 4) { //4 байта на float
    result_array.push(buffer.readFloatBE(i));
}
```

Возможно надо использовать `readFloatLE`.